# Display filename with extension using FileField in Sitecore

Tags: media-library, field, mediaurls

I need to display the `filename with an extension` for a `File` type field in `Sitecore SXA 10.2`. The field value in content contains an `Url` that points to the pdf documents in `Media Library`.

```
var fileField = (FileField)item.Fields[fileFieldName];
if (fileField == null) return string.Empty;
var file = fileField.MediaItem;
```

Is it possible to obtain the filename with an extension using MediaItem with FileField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You already have `MediaItem` object. So I can think of 2 ways to get the filename with an extension.

**1. Using MediaUrlBuilderOptions get the full URL and split it to get the filename with the extension.**

You need to build the URLs by using the `MediaUrlBuilderOptions` classes for media items.

```
Sitecore.Links.UrlBuilders.MediaUrlBuilderOptions mediaUrlBuilderOptions = new MediaUrlBuilderOptions
{
    IncludeExtension = true,
};

var fileField = (FileField)item.Fields[fileFieldName];
if (fileField == null) return string.Empty;
var file = fileField.MediaItem;

string urlWithExtention = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(file, mediaUrlBuilderOptions);

string fileName = urlWithExtention.Split('/').Last();
```

**2. Using string concatenation.**

```
var fileField = (FileField)item.Fields[fileFieldName];
if (fileField == null) return string.Empty;

Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem file = fileField.MediaItem;

string fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", file.Name, file.Extension);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way.

First we need to get the instance of the XML field by its name:

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.XmlField fileField = item.Fields["File"];
```

Now we can read the media ID using the same approach.

```
Sitecore.Data.ID mediaID = Sitecore.Data.ID.Parse(fileField.GetAttribute("mediaid"));
```

After that we can search for the media item in the context database:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem mediaItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.Items[mediaID];
```

If the item is found, we can read any property of the MediaItem object:

```
if (mediaItem != null)
{
    imageControl.ImageUrl = Sitecore.StringUtil.EnsurePrefix('/', mediaItem.InnerItem["Path"]);
}
```

Using the mediaItem object you can get all the properties like `Extension, Name, DisplayName` etc.